# Unnecessary/broken check for abstract intermediary subclass of sealed class required in exhaustive when

Tags: kotlin, pattern-matching, sealed-class

I have a sealed class hierarchy like so:

```
sealed class Base

class A : Base()

abstract class B : Base()

class C : Base()
class D : Base()
```

Then I want to have an exhaustive `when`:

```
fun main() {
    val c: Base = C()
    
    when (c) {
        is A -> println("A")
        is C -> println("C")
        is D -> println("D")
    }.let {}
}
```

But this is not allowed because

```
'when' expression must be exhaustive, add necessary 'is B' branch or 'else' branch instead
```

But that's not true! I've covered all  possibilities. There is no value that isn't matched by my when.

Furthermore, if I *do* add a `is C` clause:

```
when (c) {
    is A -> println("A")
    is B -> println("B")
    is C -> println("C")
    is D -> println("D")
}.let {}
```

It isn't actually *called*. `C` is printed.

This is actually a problem in the other direction, too. Say I want the same logic to handle all subclasses of `B`: `C` and `D`:

```
when (c) {
    is A -> println("A")
    is B -> println("some subclass of B")
}.let {}
```

That's also not allowed, even though it *is* exhaustive. What's going on here? Is this a bug in Kotlin? Am I missing something?

Comment: Why is `B` not a valid type? Any implementation of `B` is still a type of `Base`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant for C and D to be subclasses of B rather than Base, then this behavior is expected. The ability of the compiler to recognize an exhaustive when statement only extends to the direct children of the sealed class. C and D are not part of the sealed class contract. This works with your existing class setup if C and D extend B:

```
when (c) {
    is A -> println("A")
    is B -> println("B")
}.let {}
```

And if you make B a sealed class, just like A, your original code works and the compiler can recognize that it's exhaustive without including B in the when statement.